# jQuery Sliding Panels - Positioning Divs side by side.

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an application wizard that is supposed to slide panels to show the other sections of the resume application. This is my site:
http://atomicflowtech.com/portfolio/fmsresume/
When you CLICK anywhere on the form you can see the effect I am trying to achieve, but panels are under each other and then they slide up. Any clue how to fix this? I am sorry if the question is badly phrased, I just couldn't figure out how to explain it better and the example speaks for itself I think. Thanks for your help!

I am trying to achieve this effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/2/

Comment: Why don't you just use the same method that the jsfiddle uses?

Comment: @DylanCross I'm using the same method, but it works in absolutes, which means it centers on the middle of the screen. I need it to just be in that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you just need to float that container left. should do the trick. let me know how it goes

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with the link?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box">Div #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box">Div #5</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0px;    
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.box').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
        left: '-50%'
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).css('left', '150%');
        $(this).appendTo('#container');
    });

    $(this).next().animate({
        left: '50%'
    }, 500);
});​
```

​
You just have to change the content, isn't?
​

Comment: Excellent solution. Thank you